# Using @Transaction annotation with @Autowired - Spring

Tags: java, spring

Well, i have a Class with @Service annotation and some strange occurrs: When i put the annotation @Transaction in some method i can't start tomcat server, i got error: "Can not autowired..." in another class when i use my @Autowired, but when i remove the @Transaction all works fine.

My class header is:

```
@Service(value = "caixaBO")
public class CaixaBOImpl extends BasicBOImpl {
```

And my method signature is:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void movimentarCaixaPaciente(String descricao, double valor,
        Paciente paciente) {
```

When i use @Autowired CaixaBOImpl caixaBO, i got error in tomcat initialized because the annotation @Transaction.

**EDIT 1:**

1 - I have transactionManager in applicationContext.xml, look:

```
<!-- Configuracao do gerente de transacoes do Spring -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
```

2 - I have CGLIB in pom.xml, look:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

**EDIT 2**

My stack trace:

```
Grave: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pedidoProteseBO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private br.com.odontonew.financeiro.bo.CaixaBOImpl br.com.odontonew.odonto.bo.PedidoProteseBOImpl.caixaBO; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set br.com.odontonew.financeiro.bo.CaixaBOImpl field br.com.odontonew.odonto.bo.PedidoProteseBOImpl.caixaBO to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5204)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5199)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private br.com.odontonew.financeiro.bo.CaixaBOImpl br.com.odontonew.odonto.bo.PedidoProteseBOImpl.caixaBO; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set br.com.odontonew.financeiro.bo.CaixaBOImpl field br.com.odontonew.odonto.bo.PedidoProteseBOImpl.caixaBO to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set br.com.odontonew.financeiro.bo.CaixaBOImpl field br.com.odontonew.odonto.bo.PedidoProteseBOImpl.caixaBO to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:164)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:168)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:741)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:504)
    ... 22 more
```

Answer (score 6):

There are two situations I can think of that might cause this

1. You haven't declared a `TransactionManager` and therefore `@Transactional` advice cannot be applied.
2. Your `@Autowired` target is declared as a field of type `CaixaBOImpl` and you don't have `CGLIB` libraries on your classpath for Spring to create class proxies. As such, it creates JDK Proxies which it fails to inject because the types don't match. [You can get the `CGLIB` libraries here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/cglib/cglib). Or you can change the `@Autowired` target field to type `BasicBOImpl`. This will be a problem if you are injecting other beans of type `BasicBOImpl` in your application without qualifying them with an id.

It seems that even though you have the CGLIB proxies, Spring is using JDK proxies anyway. Change your `tx:annotation-driven` declaration to

```
<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" />
```

Comment: So, i have answer for you 2 question in my post edit. Read please.

Comment: @user2776409 Please post your exception stack trace. and the injection target.

Comment: I posted my stack trace.

Comment: Good, it's work. But i didn't understand this concept. WHat is JDK and Spring Proxies, how this works ?

Comment: @user2776409: see http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-introduction-proxies and http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies

Comment: @user2776409 In addition to the recommended readings that JB posted, you should also familiarize yourself with the JDK's [`Proxy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) class. The javadoc states: `A proxy class extends java.lang.reflect.Proxy.` Therefore, the object that Spring is trying to inject is of type `Proxy`, not `CaixaBOImpl`, although it will be of type `BasicBOImpl` because that is an interface.

Answer (score 0):

We encountered a similar problem and we used a "hack" that seems to be working. Simply make your class implement some interface.
It worked for us - let me know if it works for you too.