# Generic Autowiring Not Working with @Transactional

Tags: java, spring, generics, autowired

Spring appears fully capable of autowiring the correct type based on generic parameters without the need for `@Qualifier`s. However, as soon as I tack on a `@Transactional` annotation, it can no longer autowire based on generic parameters. Consider this example, invented only for purposes of illustrating the issue:

```
interface Product {}

interface Book extends Product {}

interface Toy extends Product {}

interface Store<P extends Product> {}

@Component
class BookStore implements Store<Book> {}

@Component
class ToyStore implements Store<Toy> {}

@Component    
class BookDealer {

  @Autowired
  BookDealer(Store<Book> store) {
     ...
  }

  void inventoryBooks() {
     ... doesn't really matter what this does ...
  }
}
```

Note that the above code wires up fine. The `BookStore` class is autowired into the `BookDealer` constructor without any issue. I can call `inventoryBooks()` and it works fine.

However, if I add a `@Transactional` annotation to a method upstream from the call to `inventoryBooks()`, e.g. on the client method that calls it, the `BookDealer` will no longer autowire, and I must resort to either injecting concrete types, or using a `@Qualifier`. The error is that there are two matching beans for the constructor argument of `BookDealer`, meaning both the `BookStore` and the `ToyStore` and Spring can't decide which one is needed. That tells me that Spring can no longer detect the generic types now that some upstream method has been proxied for the `@Transactional`. Something like that anyway...

I would like to stick to interfaces and not use `@Qualifier`s. Is there a way to do this with `@Transactional`, or is it a known limitation of generics and autowiring and things like `@Transactional`?

Comment: Were you able to determine why generic autowiring didn't work with @Transactional?

Comment: I did not, Sorry.

Comment: Nuts...currently stepping through GenericCollectionTypeResolver, ResolvableType, GenericTypeAwareAutowireCandidateResolver, to get a better understanding of whats happening behind the scenes.

Answer (score -1):

The Spring uses the JDK Proxy to generate the proxy used in AOP by default. The JDK proxy is based on the interface. So it maybe the problem, when you need to autowire the concrete class. So use the cglib instead(add the denpendency) and set the "" in the spring config file to "" and have a try. Hope it helps.
[Using @Transaction annotation with @Autowired - Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19624354/using-transaction-annotation-with-autowired-spring)