# After add @Transactional on method , this class(service) can't Autowired bean(repository)?

Tags: spring, jpa, proxy, transactional

1. @EnableTransactionManagement is added on MyBootApplication
2. `@Bean
   public Object testBean(PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager){
       System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>TransactionManager is " + platformTransactionManager.getClass().getName());
       return new Object();
   }`
   it print TransactionManager is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager
3. `@Service open class UserService : BaseService() {
     @Autowired lateinit var repository: UserRepository
     @Transactional
     fun updateValid(id: Long, valid: Boolean) {
       ErrorConstant.ParamErrorCode.IdIsNull.caseThrow { id == 0.toLong() }
       repository.updateValid(id,valid)
     }
   }`

i use spring.boot to build my project.

when i remove the @Transactional,everything is fine .

but when i add it. the repository is null,it can't be inject.

i read that question [Using @Transaction annotation with @Autowired - Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19624354/using-transaction-annotation-with-autowired-spring) ,and i add `spring.aop.proxy-target-class=true` in my application.properties ,still same error .

i use kotlin to write it,but i guess this is not the reason.

even so ,i will try with java later .

**My mistake , I have some properties in BaseService , should add open on it too .**

Comment: I had the same problem because I used @Transactional from javax.transaction package. After change to org.springframework.transaction.annotation it works.

Comment: Maybe duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41298289/spring-boot-autowired-with-kotlin-in-service-is-always-null

Answer (score 1):

I have added 'open' on func yet  ,but leave out the propeties .

```
@PersistenceContext
protected open lateinit var em: EntityManager

@Autowired
protected open lateinit var env: Environment
```

Answer (score 1):

For others that might miss the resolution in bold at the bottom of the question:
All public functions should be set to open (in oppose to the implicit final default in kotlin)